Who am I? Where do I live?
I live in a house.
To the north, there's a squad of gamers living in an apartment. One of their rooms is directly at the exit of the apartment, next to my house so I sometimes visit them.
To the west, well, I won't travel there often. There's always drunk people there. I'd rather stay with the gamer squad.
To the east is a dorm of university students, faculty of mathematics. Must be a bunch of smart people in there.
To the south is their university. It's across a river. I'm not sure how someone could travel south in a ride, then enter a boat and cross the river, and still arrive on time.
Who am I? Where do I live?
Hint:

 North isn't always top.


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Thank you for the welcome!

Added a hint to the post.

I know this is not the answer but I had to post this as 2 thing match very well....
Here goes:

 you are puzzling.stackexchange.com

What do I mean?

 Go to https://stackexchange.com/sites filter by "Culture and recreation" and change the display from list view to grid view... Basically this url: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#culturerecreation
 Now you will see this 
 What fits:
  - To the north, there's a squad of gamers living in an apartment. One of their rooms is directly at the exit of the apartment, next to my house so I sometimes visit them.
  Above the puzzling website there is Sports and Chess (a bunch of gamers in an apartment). Chess is near the edge (near the exit)
 - To the west, well, I won't travel there often. There's always drunk people there. I'd rather stay with the gamer squad.
 On the left side there is "Beer, Wine & Spirits" (mmmm, beer) -you know what I mean if you are over 16, 18 or 21 (depending on the country).

What does not fit....
The other 2 (south and east). Or maybe they fit but I didn't get it.

While not the solution I had, this is a great answer!

rot13("Tb gb uggcf://fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz/fvgrf#fpvrapr (rnfg bs uggcf://fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz/fvgrf#phyghererperngvba) naq lbh jvyy svaq gur zngurzngvpf fvgr.")

Maybe this is a stretch but
You are a:

chess pawn

and you live on

e2

To the north:

(e3): This is the square right in front of you, often occupied by other pieces, like a knight (gamers in an apartment). The room directly at the exit refers to the square f3, which is often where the knight on g1 moves to early in the game.

To the west:

(d2): The square to your left, where you usually don’t go, possibly occupied by a pawn (drunk people) on d2.

To the east:

(f2): The square to your right, where your fellow pawn (university students, mathematicians) resides, often another pawn that’s part of the same pawn structure.

To the south:

(e1): The square behind you, where the king or queen starts (the university across the river, which might refer to the metaphorical "crossing" from one end of the board to the other, such as when pawns promote).

The hint:

Given that north isn’t always top, in chess, the direction “north” would refer to the direction the pawn is moving—up the board if you're the player controlling the white pieces. But when playing black north is bottom.


While not the solution I had, this is a great answer! Welcome to the site!

@kpuzzler thanks! Well i got another idea, if it's not chess related is it mahjong related?

It's not, although the size isn't that different. :)

Well i'm out of ideas, but i look forward to the next hint. :)

You said North isn't always top. So the word North lead me to think in

 NorthBridge (the communication center beetween the computer's CPU and the other critical components).

So, maybe the answer is:

 You are a computer's CPU and you're living in the MotherBoard of that CPU.

So, to the North:

 You have the MotherBoard's NorthBridge where are the critical components like RAM and GPU which are crucial to games and gameplays.

To the West:

 You have the less computational components (like the power supply) which you don't visit because they don't do any computational work.

To the East:

 You have the memory slots which are like rooms to the NorthBridge components.

To the south:

 We encounter the computer's SouthBridge. Yeah, it could be a river but the bridge allows the data connection with the outside sources (like usb connections, memory cards and another things) which are allocated on the SouthBridge of the CPU.

Maybe I'm overthinking. It's just a guess :)

This is a great answer! Not the solution I had though.

This might be a bit of a stretch but:

 You live somewhere in the Mediterranean Sea, between Cyprus and Crete.

To the north:

 Sweden, where PewDePie, a gamer, used to live.

To the west:

 Mexico, filled with drug cartels and probably drunk people as well.

To the east:

 Iraq, which had the “House of Wisdom”, which was a library (It was burnt down though).

To the south:

 Egypt, where the Library of Alexandria is located. Separated from Iraq in the East by the Suez Canal.


Great answer! Although not the solution I had.
